# convert to UTC without changing php timezone settings

Tags: php, timezone, utc

How can I convert the time zone of a date string in php without changing the default time zone. I want to convert it locally to display only. The php time zone settting should not be modified.

**EDIT:**
My source time is a UTC string, I want to convert it to a different format, retaining the time zone as UTC,  but php is converting it to local timezone. 
The code I used was:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i::s',strtotime($time_str));
```

How do I retain timezone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$src_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago');
$dest_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

$dt = new DateTime("2000-01-01 12:00:00", $src_tz);
$dt->setTimeZone($dest_tz);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note that if the source time is UTC, you can change the one line to this:

```
$dt = new DateTime("2000-01-01 12:00:00 UTC");
```

Edit: Looks like you want to go *to* UTC. In that case, just use `"UTC"` as the parameter to the `$dest_tz` constructor, and use the original block of code. (And of course, you can omit the `$src_tz` parameter if it is the same as the default time zone.)