# Set timezone as Europe/London

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I'm using PHP to insert a query into a database.

I am using `timestamp` for each query, however currently it is returning a time which is 7 hours behind my timezone (**Europe/London**).

How do I set the timezone as Europe/London when I insert it into a MYSQL database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711597/convert-to-utc-without-changing-php-timezone-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

*(I have written the code in PDO as you did not specify which extension you were using.)*

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
  $time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (datetime) VALUES ('".$time_stamp."')");
  $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are timezone independent. Please show your code however.

And make sure your db and php server are running on the same time. You can set the timezone in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I place the following at the top of my script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$formatted_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change my timezone when I set it to Europe/London... still 7 hours behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

?>
```

for mysql setting timezone like that-

```
SET time_zone = timezonename;
```

Comment: Doesn't change the timezone when I insert a query into the MYSQL database.